# Reverse order of cells of rows in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have looked at the recommendations made in previous years. I may be a bit thick here but all I seem to get is the same problem in a vertical axis. I have two large databases which I want to compare, manipulate data, draw graphs etc, but data is in reverse order from one to the other. I have a MacBook Pro with Yosemite 10.10.5 and Microsoft Office 2011. Would it help to upgrade my software? (El  Capitan and Microsoft Office 2016 don't seem entirely perfected yet.)

Comment: It's very difficult to understand your question now, please clarify it. What does it mean "reverse order"? What exactly you need to do with it? Please show some sample data. Why do you think upgrade is relevant here?

Answer (score 2):

Add a helper column to one of the tables and enter the numbers 1, 2, 3, etc. into a few cells. Double click the fill handle to fill down to the last row. Now you can sort the data by this column. Use Descending (largest to smallest) to reverse the order.

To restore the original order, sort the data by the helper column in Ascending (smallest to largest) order.

Comment: Great, simple answer. And though it may help the OP compare the data, it does not answer the question asked about upgrading software. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you have data in a single row or a single column like:

[image]

and want to invert the data. Select the cells and run this short *VBA* macro:

```
Sub InvertData()
   Dim arr() As Variant, i As Long, r As Range
   ReDim arr(1 To Selection.Count)

   i = 1
   For Each r In Selection
      arr(i) = r.Value
      i = i + 1
   Next r

   i = Selection.Count
   For Each r In Selection
      r.Value = arr(i)
      i = i - 1
   Next r

End Sub
```

Will produce:

[image]

Your computer and version of Office should support *VBA*